# Intersection of kernel of commuting nilpotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $N$ and $Q$ are two nilpotent matrices which commute. Is it true that $\ker N \cap \ker Q \ne \{ 0\}$?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, isn't the claim in that case trivially true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if one excludes the $0\times0$ matrix this is true. Take any nonzero vector$~v$, let $i>0$ be minimal such that $N^iv=0$, then $0\neq v'=N^{i-1}v\in\ker N$. Now let $j>0$ be minimal such that $Q^jv'=0$, then $0\neq v''=Q^{j-1}v\in\ker Q$. But also $Nv''=NQ^{j-1}v'=Q^{j-1}Nv'=0$ so $v''\in\ker N\cap\ker Q$.